# Powershell command to select one value

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

My PowerShell command is working fine as below :

```
PS C:\Users\username> whoami /user

USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name        SID
================ ==============================================
wip\username     S-1-5-21-57989841-616248376-1811674531-4551702
```

But when I try to select only SID, it is showing blank

```
PS C:\Users\username> whoami /user | Select-Object "User information"

User information
----------------
blank
```

I am expecting "S-1-5-21-57989841-616248376-1811674531-4551702" instead of blank

Comment: Pleaase add as an answer, i will accept , thanks

Comment: Just like Mathias mentions, that's not a cmdlet, that's an executable. In order for you to work with it, there's several ways to do so, but the easiest is having it output as a csv, then converting it into an object. `whoami /user /FO csv | convertfrom-csv | select blah`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whoami` is not a PowerShell cmdlet - it's an executable - so the output is text, not an object you can manipulate with `Select-Object`.

You can get your current SID from:

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User
```

Comment: Or (using actually a [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview)): `(get-localuser $Env:Username).SID.Value`

Comment: @iRon `wip` doesn't sound like the name of a machine and `4551702` seems a bit high for a local SAM RID to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to remove header and manipulate with the result as we know it's format and structure.

The following command prints an SID of the first user in the list:

```
(whoami /user /nh).Split(" ")[1]
```

In case of many users you have to select the line by username first.